# How to write multiple times to the child process from the several part of the parent code(QProcess)?

Tags: python, c++, qt5, qprocess, qiodevice

I'm a beginner in QT, and I'm trying to send/write some data from the parent process(C++) to the child process(python) and the child process need to receive that data.

**Parent code:**

```
    if(PythonProcess.state() == QProcess::Running){
            QString data1 = "starttttttttttttttt123";
            PythonProcess.write(data1.toStdString().c_str());
            PythonProcess.write("\n\r");
            PythonProcess.closeWriteChannel();
            //PythonProcess.start();
            //PythonProcess.waitForBytesWritten();
            data1 = "newwwwwoneeee\n";
            //PythonProcess.write(data1.toStdString().c_str());
            PythonProcess.write("\n");
            //std::cout <<data1.toStdString().c_str()<<endl;
            //PythonProcess.waitForBytesWritten();
            //PythonProcess.closeWriteChannel();
        }
```

**Child process:**

```
    while True:
        for line in sys.stdin:
            print(line)
```

**Problems:**

When I'm using QProcess::write() to write data, I need to put QProcess::closeWriteChannel() to write the data to stdin. Without this the data isn't written to the child process.
But once I closed the write channel, there's no way back to open it again without restarting the process.
So if I write one time, and close the channel,  the 2nd time it won't work in the same process.
But I must send multiple data time to time to the child process without restarting it.

**Question**

How can I send the data multiple time to the child process without closing the write channel or without restarting the child process?
An example will be great.

Comment: Does QT have a `flush` command? You can use this command in Python to force the output of the buffer to the `stdout`

Comment: I didn't find any flush option in QT, But yeah python has it.